# 64GB SSD, 20GB visible, HPA disabled

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, disk-space

I have a 64GB OCZ Agility 4 SSD that only shows 20GB available.  My first thought was HPA was enabled, so I fired up hdparm only to learn that HPA is disabled.

```
root@PartedMagic:~# hdparm -N /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 max sectors   = 41943036/41943036, HPA is disabled
```

I tried to set the correct number of sectors anyway, with no luck.

```
root@PartedMagic:~# hdparm -N p134217728 /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 setting max visible sectors to 134217728 (permanent)
 SET_MAX_ADDRESS failed: Input/output error
 max sectors   = 41943036/41943036, HPA is disabled
```

I tried to set a slightly smaller size, and it sort of failed.

```
root@PartedMagic:~# hdparm -N p41943035 /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 setting max visible sectors to 41943035 (permanent)
 SET_MAX_ADDRESS failed: Input/output error
 READ_NATIVE_MAX_ADDRESS_EXT failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Then I saw that the sector size and max sector size both decreased, but HPA still showed disabled.

```
root@PartedMagic:~# hdparm -N /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 max sectors   = 41943034/41943034, HPA is disabled
```

I couldn't even set it back to the original incorrect sector size.

```
root@PartedMagic:~# hdparm -N p41943036 /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 setting max visible sectors to 41943036 (permanent)
 SET_MAX_ADDRESS failed: Input/output error
 max sectors   = 41943034/41943034, HPA is disabled
```

Trying to display the DCO information didn't work, either.

```
root@PartedMagic:~# hdparm --dco-identify /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(dco_identify) failed: Input/output error
```

I went ahead and tried to reset DCO, but it also failed.

```
root@PartedMagic:~# hdparm --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing --dco-restore /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 issuing DCO restore command
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(dco_restore) failed: Input/output error
```

I used PartedMagic's secure erase, which completed, but still didn't restore the correct drive size.  I used OCZ's utility to upgrade the firmware, but that didn't help.  Neither did OCZ's secure erase.

I'm at a loss here.  I have no idea where to go next.  Please help me get this drive restored to the proper size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a thread for this on OCZ's official forum. The answer I received from their support guy is that it's a known issue that can't be fixed by an end user.  Since the drive is well out of warranty, there is nothing I can do about it.  [Here is a link](http://oczforum.com/forum/discussion/comment/5200) to the thread for reference.  I guess the take-away for me with this is to make sure a device's supported features won't actually brick said device before using them.